# dcast running out of memory - alternatives?

Tags: r, memory, sparse-matrix, reshape2, dcast

I am trying to reshape a (very) long table into a wide (very sparse) table.

The dimensions:

```
dim(data)
[1] 16146436        3
```

If i attempt the standard `dcast` operation it fails due to running out of memory:

```
datac <- dcast(formula=gene ~ sample, value.var="Coverage", data=data)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 23399.6 Gb
```

Any suggestions on either making `dcast` run or alternatives that are optimized for large very sparse datasets?

Comment: Try `library(data.table);`  `dcast.data.table(formula=gene ~ sample, value.var="Coverage", data=data)`

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same issue: `> dcast.data.table(formula=gene ~ sample, value.var="Coverage", data=data.table(data))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11699.8 Gb`

Comment: data.table is usually preferred for large data set. If possible, try the divide and conquer approach by doing dcast for subsets of data.

Comment: save your data in the disk, free workspace, and then read it using `fread`. You can control the number of rows by `nrows` argument in `fread`

Comment: for example: `dcast.data.table(fo‌​rmula=gene ~ sample, value.var="Coverage"‌​, data= fread("filename", nrows = 1000L))`

Comment: `fread` does not have the ability to specify number of rows or its interval. If possible, split the data into chunks and save it in disk, then with `fread` read the chunks and `dcast` them. A better approach would be to read chunks of data from a database.

Comment: It might be helpful to specify in what ways that table is sparse. Suggest providing the first 20 lines of data.

Comment: Yeah, if it's sparse in the sense of having a ton of zeros in Coverage, I'd just filter out the zeros and find a way to work with the data in long format. Alternately, some packages support sparse matrix data structures.

Comment: use `data.table::tables()` to track the memory space used by data.table objects.

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/casting-a-wide-and-sparse-matrix-in-r/